# EXCEL VBA regarding functions & userforms

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I am new in Excel VBA programming therefore I've met a few difficulties within my very own project.

Long story short, I have 10 UserForm(s), and 10 TextBox(s) in each UserForm with the same TextBox name.

Is it possible for me to create a function that I can call it in every UserForm so that I don't have to manually code it for every UserForm(s). Regarding the function, it will reset the value of TextBox, as well as bring it back to the 'initial' state.

That's all for my question. Any help would be highly appreciate.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `Sub` in a `Module` that you call from each form

eg

```
Sub TextBoxInit(tb As MSForms.TextBox)
    tb.Text = ""
End Sub
```

Call it in each `UserForm` as you see fit

eg

```
Private Sub Userform_Initialize()
    Module1.TextBoxInit TextBox1
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your fast response. Basically I want the **TextBox.value = ""** upon **Userform_Initialize()**. Is that possible?

Comment: Very efficient indeed using this method. Thanks a lot Chris. Very appreciate that.

Comment: Furthermore, if you want to initialize all the text boxes on the form you can loop through them:

    <code>Private Sub Userform_Initialize()
        Dim crtl As MSForms.Control

        For Each crtl In Me.Controls
            If TypeName(crtl) = "TextBox" Then
                Module1.TextBoxInit crtl
            End If
       Next crtl
    End Sub</code>

Answer (score 0):

Tan,

You should think about making use of **Class Modules**. I actually just learned about them recently, and they are a very effective way to manage multiple userforms with similarly constructed controls.

Go Here: [VBA USERFORM: PREVENT COMBOBOX ESCAPE ON KEYDOWN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17583823/vba-userform-prevent-combobox-escape-on-keydown/17775896#17775896)

Or Here: [EXCEL VBA: dblClick, Repetitive Code Improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17756216/excel-vba-dblclick-repetitive-code-improvement/17756823#17756823)

The basics of how these Class Modules work is that you create your own object, you write the code for it, and you assign your desired userform controls as that object type (class). For instance, if you had 20 textboxes which performed the same way (they rebooted their own values), you would just write that identical code in the class module section. Bam! That's pretty much it (you'd also have to write a paragraph of code to loop through & assign which textboxes you'd want this functionality for).

It might take a while to understand, but it will significantly improve your project.