# EXCEL VBA: dblClick, Repetitive Code Improvement

Tags: excel, vba, events, userform, repeat

I have a bunch of similarly constructed userforms with many identical objects on them. For my labels (which number over 50), I have created a dblClick event to allow the users to change the caption. This is working fine-&-all, but I'm wondering if there's a way for me to improve my code.

Is there a way to be able to avoid making dozens of copies of the same code just to handle the same event on different objects?

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Item1_Label_dblClick(ByVal Cancel as MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Item1_Label.Caption = InputBox("blah?", "blah", Item1_Label.Caption)
        if Item1_Label.Caption = "" Then Item1_Label.Caption = "Item 1"
End Sub

Private Sub Item2_Label_dblClick(ByVal Cancel as MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Item2_Label.Caption = InputBox("blah?", "blah", Item2_Label.Caption)
        if Item2_Label.Caption = "" Then Item2_Label.Caption = "Item 2"
End Sub

Private Sub Item3_Label_dblClick(ByVal Cancel as MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Item3_Label.Caption = InputBox("blah?", "blah", Item3_Label.Caption)
        if Item3_Label.Caption = "" Then Item3_Label.Caption = "Item 3"
End Sub

'etcetera etcetera
```

I have over 50 of these clone lines of code in my userform. I think there is a better way to do it, but when I [looked](http://yoursumbuddy.com/userform-event-handler-class-multiple-controls/) up using a Class EventHandler, I couldn't see how to apply it for my purposes.

Is there a way to prevent this repetitive code?

Thanks,

Elias

Comment: The link you posted should work for labels...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'clsLabel
Public WithEvents oLabel As MSForms.Label

Public Sub oLabel_dblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    MsgBox oLabel.Caption
End Sub



'form code
Private colLabels As Collection

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim o As Control, l As clsLabel
Set colLabels = New Collection
For Each o In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(o) = "Label" Then
        Set l = New clsLabel
        Set l.oLabel = o
        colLabels.Add l
    End If
Next o
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Well, I'm off to a good start so far (I had to research 'Collection' and 'clsLabel'). The trouble, though, is that the double click action is not working. Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Well, it works for me...  Hard to tell what the issue is with your version of the code.  Have you tried debugging to make sure the collection is being populated?

Comment: I've typed "print colLabels(1)" in the Immediate window, but that does not work. I am very very green on Class Modules; and I've learned more in these past 30 minutes than I ever knew. I still cannot get this to work, though. (Excel 2013)

Comment: If you add a breakpoint on `Set l.oLabel = o` does it enter the break when your form loads? Or add `Debug.print o.Name` just after that line and see what you get in the Immediate window.

Comment: Yeah, the "Debug.print o.Name" is working. It prints out only the names of each label within my form. Also, the breakpoint stops at the "Set l.oLabel = o" line. Is the problem with my clsLabel?

Comment: What part of my code? It's pretty massive (1.6 MBs, almost all VBA). I've been searching through the internet to no avail. I've got a pretty good understanding [now] of what your code is designed to do. It's just that the dblClick event is not registering. What gives? Do I need to initialize my class? What part of my code would you like to see?

Comment: Tim! I got it to work. It had to do with the "Collection" declaration. I had to move it and change its level. It's working like a charm. I will edit your post above with my code and check it off. Thanks so much for your help, brotha!

Comment: Good to hear you got it sorted.